# mongod not running with default directory (/data/db) on big sur / can not create default directory

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

I'm reposting this question and deleted the old one since I had some misconceptions I guess.

I'm new to unix based terminals - that upfront.

Installed mongod via homebrew. I can only make `mongod` run if I give a custom `data/db` path as parameter on startup. My goal is to start `mongod` via terminal without any parameters.

It does not start with the default path `/data/db` since I can not create that folder manually on my system (big sur). So entering `mongod` without anything will fail.

I tried to create that folder with `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` which tells me `Read-only filesystem`.

My research told me, that I can not create this folder anymore since Catalina. Is that true and I do have to start mongod with a --dbpath parameter on any OS after catalina?

this works since it is a custom path:

`sudo mkdir -p data/db`
`sudo mongod --dbpath data/db`

the following does not work:

`sudo mkdir -p /data/db`
`sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db`
`sudo mongod`
`mongod`

I'm aware that `/data/db` is different from `data/db`

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've installed via homebrew, you can edit the configuration file at `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` to use whatever data directory you like, and then start mongod by running

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

If you prefer a simpler to type command, edit your `~/.bashrc` file to contain something like

```
alias startmongod="brew services start mongodb-community@4.4"
```

Then open a new terminal and run `startmongo`.

Note that if you use a shell other than bash, you may need to edit a different rc file.

Comment: very good idea! thank you. Would upvote if I can :) 
Will give it a try